# XSLT help - Retrieving an ID of an element

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XSLT to select and loop through objects with a certain parentID, this is working fine. What I then need to do is check the ID of each selected element of the XML against a value.

Here is my code:

XSL:

```
<xsl:for-each select="categories/category[@parentId='1333']">
    <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="id='1349'">Yes</xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>No</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Here is an example XML block:

```
 <categories>
    <category !!!!THIS IS THE ID I WANT!!!!! id="1348" parentId="1333">
      <name>Name</name>  
      <description>Desc</description>  
      <path>/test/test/testing</path> 
    <category id="1349" parentId="1333">
      <name>Name</name>  
      <description>Desc</description>  
      <path>/test/test/testing</path> 
    </category>  
    <category id="1352" parentId="1333">
      <name>Name</name>  
      <description>Desc</description>  
      <path>/test/test/testing</path> 
    </category>  
    <category id="1370" parentId="1333">
      <name>Name</name>  
      <description>Desc</description>  
      <path>/test/test/testing</path> 
    </category>  
  </categories>
```

Comment: Your `for-each` is looking for `@parentId='1333'`, but the element in the XML you say you want has `@parentId='1202'`... can you explain?

Comment: Also, your `<xsl:when test="id='1349'">` should be `<xsl:when test="@id='1349'">` (note the extra `@`)

Comment: For future reference, just editing a small bit of the code is not very obvious - it's better if you either make a note within the question that you've updated that particular part, or put a comment under the question. (And remember, if you're replying to a particular commenter, you should use their name, e.g. @user1442404 so they are directly notified - [see here for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's simply that you're not checking for the attribute correctly.

Change...

```
<xsl:when test="id='1349'">
```

To (note the extra `@` which means it's an attribute name rather than an element name)...

```
<xsl:when test="@id='1349'">
```

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need an `xsl:for-each` and `xsl:choose` to locate and process the wanted element(s).**

Just have a template matching the wanted elements:

```
<xsl:template match="categories/category[@id='1349' and @parentId='1333']">
  <!-- Your processing here -->
</xsl:template>
```